# Assume that you roll 2 dice and calculate the sum, what is the probability that the sum is at least 7 or even?

Tags: probability

Assume that you roll 2 dice and calculate the sum, what is the probability that the sum is at least 7 or even, and I'm stuck because I have written all possibilities that I can think of.

Here's what I have written:
Sum 7: 6 ways (1+6, 2+5, 3+4, 4+3, 5+2, and 6+1)
Sum 8: 5 ways (2+6, 3+5, 4+4, 5+3, and 6+2)
Sum 9: 4 ways (3+6, 4+5, 5+4, and 6+3) 
Sum 10: 3 ways (4+6, 5+5, and 6+4)\
Sum 11: 2 ways (5+6 and 6+5)\
Sum 12: 1 way (6+6)
i.e., 21 ways and for even it's
Sum 2: 1 way (1+1)
Sum 4: 3 ways (1+3, 2+2, and 3+1)
Sum 6: 5 ways (1+5, 2+4, 3+3, 4+2, and 5+1)
Sum 8: 5 ways (2+6, 3+5, 4+4, 5+3, and 6+2)
Sum 10: 3 ways (4+6, 5+5, and 6+4)
Sum 12: 1 way (6+6) 18 ways
which means the probability is $$(21/36) + (18/36) - (1/6) = (39/36) - (1/6) = 38/36 = 19/18.$$ ( -1/6 ) is when both happen at the same time. But this gives me 38/36. I don't understand how the probability is greater than 1.

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: You can take a very primitive approach to this if you like, draw a grid of all 36 possibilities and see how many satisfy your conditions!

Comment: Also, see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more detailed information.

Comment: edit your question and write your efforts in the question body

Comment: You miscalculated the overlap (sum=8,10,12).

Comment: (21/36)+(18/36)−(1/6)=(39/36)−(9/36) ? .

Comment: It is easier here to talk about the opposite... that the sum is not $3$ and the sum is not $5$.  Any other sum is fine.  $1 - \frac{2}{36}-\frac{4}{36}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(A)=P(the sum is at least $7$)

P(B)=P(sum is even)

$$\text{P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)}=$$
$$= \frac{21}{36}+\frac{18}{36}-\frac{9}{36}=\frac{30}{36}=\frac{5}{6}$$

Sum is at least $7$ :$(1;6),(2;5),(2;6),...,(6;5),(6;6)$,that is $21$ pairs

Sum is even : $(1;1),(1;3),...,(6;4),(6;6)$, that is  $18$ pairs

Sum is at least $7$ and Sum is even : $(2;6),(3;5),..,(6;6)$, that is $9$ pairs